# MongoDB TTL index does not remove an expired record

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I created a TTL index on my collection's `created_at` field to autoremove document after 30s but after sometime passed (5min later) the document didn't get removed. I read some related questions and I'm sure there was no typo in my collection.
Here is the JSON after running `db[collectionName].getIndexes()`

```
[
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "record_db.collectionName"
},
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "created_at" : 1.0
    },
    "name" : "created_at_1",
    "ns" : "record_db.collectionName",
    "expireAfterSeconds" : 30.0
}
```

]
And here is an example document:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5fc3823af29f9d9eb1518857"),
  "record_path" : path/to/file,
  "timestamp" : 1606648392,
  "humantime" : "29/11/2020 18:12:58",
  "created_at" : ISODate("2020-11-29T18:12:58.859Z")
}
```

Comment: Show a schema definition

Comment: ISODate("2020-11-29T18:12:58.859Z") not happened yet , that's why haven't expire

Comment: Depends on a timezone where @manaclan runs this code

Comment: @Anatoly I don't define a schema in my code, just push json to mongo. The code is: created_at = datetime.now() in python

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial The created_at file is defined in python by datetime.now() so I don't think it's not happened

Comment: regardless of timezone it still not yet happened.

Comment: at the time of posting this comment, it is now 2020-11-29T12:11:46+0000 UTC.

Comment: Yup, you're right

Comment: You may have mixed up your local time + mongodb time when you are handling creation of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISODate("2020-11-29T18:12:58.859Z") not happened yet.

```js
const iso = "2020-11-29T18:12:58.859Z"

const date = new Date(iso);
console.log(date.toString());
```